# Can I store a PromiseResult in a variable? (Vue3)

Tags: javascript, promise, vuejs3

I'm trying to set a dynamic background image, which I get from unsplash API.
The image URL is inside my `DynamicBG` function, but I can't use it as a template literal.

```
const DynamicBG = async (ConditionCode: number) => {
  try {
    const unsplashQuery = mapConditionToUnsplashKeyword(ConditionCode);
    const imageUrl = await fetchUnsplashImage(unsplashQuery);
    console.log('fetched url', imageUrl);
    return imageUrl;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching image:', error);
    return '';
  }
};

let fetchedUrl = imageUrl

<template>
    <div v-if="weatherData">
      <div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${fetchedUrl})` }"
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

When I `console.log` the `imageUrl` inside the function, it returns a image URL.
I want to use that URL as a dynamic background.

Comment: Nothing in your code is typed as a `PromiseResult`. Looks like a class name if you capitalize it like that - you just mean "promise result"? So you just mean the image URL? Sure, the image URL is just a string that can be a [ref](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html) or just a value. The rules of JavaScript still apply. The `const imageUrl` only exists within the `DynamicBG` function you created. Shouldn't it rather be `let fetchedUrl = await DynamicBG(100);` or whatever ConditionCode you want.

Comment: `imageUrl` is only defined inside the function, not outside of it. And you're never calling the function anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `ref` for the image URL.

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
const imgURL = ref('default url');
onMounted(() => {
    DynamicBG(someNum).then(res => imgURL.value = res);
});
</script>
<template>
    <div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${imgURL})` }"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks, chatGPT couldn't answer it :)